# Bizarre Result on Safari for iPhone: OL LI A or UL LI A

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari

I'm trying to use this HTML:

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="link">link</a>
    <li><a href="link">link</a>
</ol>   

<ol>
    <li>Some Link: <a href="link">link</a>
    <li>Some Link: <a href="link">link</a>
</ol>
```

On iPhone or the simulator, I get this result:

[image: strange rendering of unordered list with links]

Why is this happening, and what are some possible workarounds?

**Note:** This affects `UL` lists in the same way. It does not happen on iPad (only on iPhone and, I suppose, iPod touch).

Comment: Bizarre indeed. Is it the same for ul elements (as in the title)?

Comment: Thanks @BoltClock, yes, this happens to `UL` elements in the same way. The cheapest solution is to put a `&nbsp;` after the `<li>`, but that's visible. Ugh...

Comment: I can't even use `&zwnj;` after the `<li>` as it doesn't work. Only `&nbsp;` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround 1

```
ol, ul {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Source: http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/04/iphone-text-resizing/

As noted in the link, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) uses `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` out of the box.

As for why this workaround works, [MDN's document on `text-size-adjust`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust) may help.

## Workaround 2

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```